# I can't install Canon Pixma MG2520 Printer with Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit

Tags: printing, canon, pixma

I plugged the printer in, Ubuntu recognized it in system settings but can't find a driver for it. I downloaded several driver files for Linux, extracted them but still the same result. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this'll help a bit.Post back if not!

http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0301264001.html